# Custom event not captured by component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, custom-events

Here is my components architecture

[image]

The component `<ListButtonMenu>` emits a custom event `display-error` as below. The emission works fine as I can see the event in VueDevtools:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="saveList()">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        list: Object
    },
    methods: {
        saveList() {
            this.$emit('display-error');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

The component `<ErrorMessage>` contains a `div` element which listen to the custom event and calls a method `display()`. The method changes the component CSS class in order to display himself: `v-on:display-error="display"`. Unfortunately this does not work and the CSS class is not changed. What am I missing?

```
<template>
    <div id="errorMessage" v-bind:class="cssClass" v-on:display-error="display()">
        <div class="row justify-content-center alert alert-danger alert-dismissable text-danger">
            Error: {{ errorMessage }}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            'cssClass': 'd-none',
            'errorMessage': 'Hello'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        display() {
            this.cssClass = 'show';
            this.errorMessage='Goodbye';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my `ErrorMessage` and `ListButtonMenu` components do not have a parent-child relationship, I opted for a different solution than using custom events.

Instead, I am using my application state (built using Vuex store) as an event bus to update an `errorObject` and the `ErrorMessage` component uses computed properties to capture the `errorObject` and displays himself.

My component architecture remains the same as in the question.
Here is the file *store.js*:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        errorObject: {
            flag: false,
            message: ''
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the *ListButtonMenu* component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="saveList()">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        list: Object
    },
    methods: {
        saveList() {
            this.$store.state.errorObject.flag = true;
            this.$store.state.errorObject.message = 'My error mesage';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And here the *ErrorMessage* component;

```
<template>
    <div id="errorMessage" v-bind:class="cssClass">
        <div class="row justify-content-center alert alert-danger alert-dismissable text-danger">
            Error: {{ errorMessage }}
            <button type="button" class="close" v-on:click="close()">
                &times;
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
        }
    },
    computed: {
        cssClass() {
            if (this.$store.state.errorObject.flag) { return 'display' }
            else { return 'd-none' }
        },
        errorMessage() {
            return this.$store.state.errorObject.message;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        close() {
            this.$store.state.errorObject.flag = false;
            this.$store.state.errorObject.message= '';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error listeners must be attached to the element emitting the event. When you have `<div id="errorMessage" v-bind:class="cssClass" v-on:display-error="display()">`, this adds a listener for when that div emits the event, but the event doesn't come form the div, it comes from your `ListButtonMenu`. You need to add the `v-on` directive to that element like so:

```
<ListButtonMenu v-on="display()" other="attributes"></ListButtonMenu>
```

Edit:

Your ErrorMessage element needs to accept errors from a parent like this (note the added `$emit` for the close button):

```
<template>
  <div id="errorMessage" v-bind:class="cssClass" v-on:display-error="display()">
    <div class="row justify-content-center alert alert-danger alert-dismissable text-danger">
      Error: {{ errorMessage }}
      <button v-on:click="$emit('input', false)" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
      &times;
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'errorMessage',
    'value', // Generally value is used to toggle things so that v-model works
  ],
  computed: {
    cssClass() {
      return this.value ? 'show' : 'd-none';
    }
  }
  methods: {
    display() {
      this.cssClass = 'show';
      this.errorMessage='Goodbye';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And then your parent can look something like this:

```
<template>
  <error-message v-model="showError" v-bind:errorMessage="errorMessage">
  <list-button-menu v-on:display-error="displayError()"></list-button-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      errorMessage: 'Hello',
      showError: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    displayError() {
      this.showError = true;
      this.errorMessage: 'Goodbye';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added `v-on="display()"` like this `<list-button-menu v-on="display()"></list-button-menu>` which is actually in the `<ListForm>` component. It does not work because `<ListForm>` does not have any `display()` method. I have also updated the `<ListButtonMenu>` above to show the complete code. Would you mind taking a look at it and tell me if it's something I should change in there?

Comment: Before I post an update, think about how you can pass values into that error element from the parent

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you mean. Which element do you refer to when saying "that error element"? Actually `<ErrorMessage>` component is not really a parent of `<ListButtonAttribute>`. It is just higher in the hierarchy. Is this the problem and only parents of a component can capture events from child components? Also, can grand parent capture events of grand children or only from their direct children?

Comment: You have two siblings, so your parent needs to facilitate the communication. And by "that error element" I mean your error component. Every time I've said element I meant component.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your detailed answer. Basically and according to the components architecture I described above, the error info has to go from `ListButtonMenu` > `ListForm` > `List` > `App` > `ErrorMessage`. I think I will rework the architecture to make it more straight forward